# Passing parameters to dependencies through a next level service

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I understand how to resolve a named parameter if I resolve exactly that service which has that parameter. But the thing is that in my case I have such service as a dependecy. Here is the example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>();
        builder.RegisterType<Something>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        container.Resolve<Dependency>(new NamedParameter("prm", "test"));
        container.Resolve<Something>(new NamedParameter("prm", "test")); //Fails
    }
}

class Dependency
{
    public Dependency(string prm) { }
}

class Something
{
    public Something(Dependency dep) { }
}
```

It fails on the second Resolve call but I need something like this. Could you please advise something to solve it? Maybe I shoud mark the parameter to be something like this:

```
container.Resolve<Something>(new NamedParameter<Dependency>("prm", "test"));
```

Comment: What's the message ? To see what's going on, we'll need the <T> header of your generic container.Resolve() function. When T is specified there, using where-constructs, you'll need to find some common ground - e.g. a common root class - between types "Dependency" and "Something". See Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: Not sure I understand it. Dependency and Something are completely different types. Their relationship is composition. They don't implement the same interfaces or something like that.

Comment: What is the error-message VS gives ? You said the second type does not work.. That is why I asked for the header of container.Resolve<T>(). If this header contains e.g. where Type T is SomeType it will only accept SomeType and classes derived from it.. and not any class !

Comment: Is is runtime error because the named parameter is not resolved

Comment: Ok that rules out my idea (you would get a compiler error) Don't know autofac but have you tried to give both constructors the "plm" parameter ? That is what you are injecting.. in Something you have a parameter named "dep" .. not "plm".

Comment: [This touches on an Autofac FAQ.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)

Comment: Thank you @TravisIllig, I have the opposite, my parameter is on low level dependency and I don't want to pass it throug all the layers. I am going to use something like I described in anwer bellow, so just sharing the parameter in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my particular problem. It supports both dynamic (run-time) and static (compile-time) values:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Dependency2>();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomethingFactory<>));
        builder.RegisterType<Something>().WithAttributeFiltering();
        var container = builder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<Something>()
            .GetPrm());
        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<SomethingFactory<Something>>()
            .GetService(new Dependency1("My test value from the factory")).GetPrm());
        Console.WriteLine("But the registration is " + container.IsRegistered<Dependency1>());
    }
}

class Dependency1
{
    private readonly string _prm;
    public Dependency1(string prm) => _prm = prm;
    public string GetPrm() => _prm;
}

class Dependency2
{
    private readonly Dependency1 _dep;
    public Dependency2(Dependency1 dep) => _dep = dep;
    public string GetPrm() => _dep.GetPrm();
}

class Something
{
    private readonly Dependency2 _dep;
    public Something([Prm("My test value from the attribute")]Dependency2 dep) => _dep = dep;
    public string GetPrm() => _dep.GetPrm();
}

class Prm : ParameterFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _prm;

    public Prm(string prm) => _prm = prm;

    public override bool CanResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
        => !context.IsRegistered<Dependency1>();

    public override object ResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
        }

        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var container = context.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
        using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder
            => builder.RegisterInstance(new Dependency1(_prm)));
        return scope.Resolve(parameter.ParameterType);
    }
}

class SomethingFactory<T>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;

    public SomethingFactory(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T GetService(Dependency1 dep)
    {
        if (dep == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dep));
        }

        using var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder => builder.RegisterInstance(dep));
        return scope.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

```
My test value from the attribute
My test value from the factory
But the registration is False
```